# Custom Java classloader and inner classes

Tags: java, class, classloader, inner-classes

I have this method (in my own classloader) that loads classes from zip:

```
ZipInputStream in = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zip));
ZipEntry entry;
while ((entry = in.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) entry.getSize()];
        in.read(buffer);
        if (!entry.getName().endsWith(".class"))
            continue;
        String name = entry.getName().replace(".class", "").replace("/", ".");
        Class<?> cls = this.defineClass(name, buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        this.resolveClass(cls);
    }
}
```

The zip that im trying to load looks like this:

```
TestClass.class
TestClass$SomeOtherInnerClass.class
```

My problem is that defineClass() fails to load the TestClass$SomeOtherInnerClass. If this class is loaded before the actual TestClass i get this:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TestClass
```

I also tried to load the TestClass.class first but then im getting this error:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Wrong InnerClasses attribute length in class file TestClass
```

Is there something i'm doing wrong?

Comment: i have the same problem, how i can load the inner classes?, my class A is loaded correctly, but my classes A$b1 no... no find a way to load the inner classes...you had any progress?

Answer (score 3):

I looks like you may not be overriding `ClassLoader.findClass()`. Without doing that, the `ClassLoader` you are extending does not know how to find these classes.

Override that function with something that simply looks up in a `private static Map<String, Class<?>>` for the class. As you load each class, put it into that map.

The difficulty will be in loading classes in the correct order, as your current implementation will not allow you to jump back to searching the Zip and calling `defineClass()` from your new `findClass()` method.

Comment: My current code looks like this: [link](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ngE2DJK9) But my problem still exists, if i try to load TestClass first it throws error because it cannot find the inner class (as its not yet defined) I don't know how to solve this :/

Answer (score 0):

There's at least one bug in that you don't (necessarily) fully read the buffer (and `ZipEntry.getSize` may return `-1`).